# Combination of different estimates of the same quantities?

Tags: variance, estimation, mean, forecast-combination

Suppose we have $n$ number of estimates for a parameter, each derived independently. How will one combine these estimates to get a single estimate which has lower variance than each individual estimate?
To tell you about the specific case I'm talking about, consider financial estimates (Revenue, Net income etc) provided by different research houses. Now to combine different estimates from different research houses to get a single estimate of a financial metric we can take average of all the available estimates (i.e form a consensus).

I was wondering if that will result in the estimate having a higher or lower variance than any individual estimate. Is there a way to ensure that the variance is less any individual estimate?
Also I would like any inputs on how to calculate the variance of individual estimate and combined estimates of the financial metric?

Comment: You would have to make sure all sources used different independent data but for comparable 'parameters'.

Comment: Yes we can assume that each source is independent to other but they use the same data ( i.e public filings and financial statements) to come up with their estimates